# How to fetch Oracle reference cursor into table variable?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, ref-cursor

I am trying to load data from reference cursor into a table variable (or array), the reference cursor works if the table variable is based on existingtable %Rowtype but my reference cursor gets 
loaded by joining multiple tables so let me try to demonstrate an example what i am trying to do and some one can help me

```
--created table
create table SAM_TEMP(
    col1 number null,
    col2 varchar(100) null
);

--created procedure which outputs results from that table

CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SP_OUT_RefCur_PARAM(
    C_RESULT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
BEGIN
    OPEN C_RESULT FOR 
        SELECT COL1,COL2
        FROM SAM_TEMP;
END SP_OUT_RefCur_PARAM;

--seeing the output works like this
DECLARE 
    REFCUR SYS_REFCURSOR;   
    outtable SAM_TEMP%rowtype ;  
BEGIN 
    SP_OUT_RefCur_PARAM(REFCUR);
    LOOP
        FETCH REFCUR INTO outtable;
        EXIT WHEN REFCUR%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(outtable.col1);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE REFCUR;
END;


--but when i try to run below script it is giving error,i think i am missing something
DECLARE 
    REFCUR SYS_REFCURSOR;   
    TYPE REFTABLETYPE IS RECORD (COL1 NUMBER, COL2  VARCHAR(100));
    TYPE TABLETYPE IS TABLE OF REFTABLETYPE;
    outtable TABLETYPE; 
BEGIN 
    SP_OUT_RefCur_PARAM(REFCUR);
    LOOP
        FETCH REFCUR INTO outtable;
        EXIT WHEN REFCUR%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(outtable.col1);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE REFCUR;
END;
```

Error report:

```
ORA-06550 line 9, column 21:
PLS-00597 expression 'OUTTABLE' in the INTO list is of wrong type
ORA-06550 line 9, column 3:
PL/SQL SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550 line 11, column 32:
PLS-00302 component 'COL1' must be declared
```

Not sure what i am missing, Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Just saw type in my answer. Actually sentence should be "Your variable outtable actually is table type."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name of variable in code above misleaded you. Your variable `outtable` is in `table` type. It isn't possible to fetch record data into table of records, but you can fetch it into record itself.

```
DECLARE 
    REFCUR SYS_REFCURSOR;   
    TYPE RECORDTYPE IS RECORD (COL1 NUMBER, COL2  VARCHAR(100));
    outtable RECORDTYPE; 
BEGIN 
    SP_OUT_RefCur_PARAM(REFCUR);
    LOOP
        FETCH REFCUR INTO outtable;
        EXIT WHEN REFCUR%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(outtable.col1);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE REFCUR;
END;
```

**Update:** If you want to fetch all data for better performance your application you need to use BULK COLLECT statement:

```
DECLARE 
    REFCUR SYS_REFCURSOR;   
    TYPE RECORDTYPE IS
        RECORD (COL1 NUMBER, COL2  VARCHAR(100));
    TYPE TABLETYPE IS
        TABLE OF REFTABLETYPE
        INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    outtable TABLETYPE; 
BEGIN 
    SP_OUT_RefCur_PARAM(REFCUR);
    LOOP
        FETCH REFCUR INTO BULK COLLECT outtable;
        EXIT WHEN outtable.COUNT = 0;

        FOR indx IN 1 .. outtable.COUNT 
        LOOP
            dbms_output.put_line(outtable(indx).col1);;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE REFCUR;
END;
```

Note: memory consumption with the BULK statement is much more than without.

> The most important thing to remember when you learn about and start to
>   take advantage of features such as BULK COLLECT is that there is no
>   free lunch. There is almost always a trade-off to be made somewhere.
>   The tradeoff with BULK COLLECT, like so many other
>   performance-enhancing features, is "run faster but consume more
>   memory." ([Oracle Magazine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html))

But if you are just fetching and processing the rows - a row at a time there is no needs in `BULK` statement, just use the cursor `FOR LOOP`. ([Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1203923200346667188))

Comment: thanks alexander,that worked, so if we are inserting record by record we need to insert into record itself, if we are bulk inserting (bulk collect) then we need to create a table variable instead of table type variable right?

Comment: @sam As I understand you, if you want to use `BULK COLLECT` you can to use just of collection of records. I just updated my answer, so you can find more information now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is this one:

```
DECLARE 
    REFCUR SYS_REFCURSOR;   
    TYPE REFTABLETYPE IS RECORD (COL1 NUMBER, COL2  VARCHAR(100));
    TYPE TABLETYPE IS TABLE OF REFTABLETYPE;
    outtable TABLETYPE; 
BEGIN 
    SP_OUT_RefCur_PARAM(REFCUR);
    FETCH REFCUR BULK COLLECT INTO outtable; 
    FOR i in outtable.First..outtable.Last Loop
        dbms_output.put_line(outtable(i).col1);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE REFCUR;
END;
```

Comment: thanks wernfried this is what i was doing and wanted to see if the other one (direct loop cursor) is faster and i got mixedup

Comment: BULK COLLECT should be faster by default.